# Serialize object without accessing certain keys?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to serialize a javascript object with about a hundred properties. 3 of those are implemented to log a warning when they are accessed (likely using a property getter implementation).

I wish to serialize the object **except** those 3 properties, and furthermore I don't even want those 3 properties to be accessed.

I tried the following (using a replacer function):

```js
const excludeProperties = ['badProp1', 'badProp2', 'badProp3']
JSON.stringify(theObject, (key, value) => excludeProperties.includes(key) ? undefined : value);
```

While the end result indeed excludes the properties from the JSON, it unfortunately doesn't prevent those properties from being accessed behind-the-scenes, so the warnings still get thrown.

Can anyone think of a fairly simple (less-code) solution to ensure these keys are never accessed?

---

Steps to reproduce:

```js
const obj = {
  goodProperty: "Serialize Me",
  get badProperty() {
    console.log("Warning: Accessed deprecated property")
    return "deprecated";
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
// Output:
// Warning: Accessed deprecated property
// {"goodProperty":"Serialize Me","badProperty":"deprecated"} 

const excludeProperties = ["badProperty"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => excludeProperties.includes(key) ? undefined : value));
// Output:
// Warning: Accessed deprecated property
// {"goodProperty":"Serialize Me"}
```

Comment: You could loop over `Object.keys()` and then just skip those you don't need

Comment: @Andy destructuring still reads the properties that I'm trying to avoid accessing.

Comment: @0stone0 That's about what I had in mind, I'm just not sure how to go from a filtered set of keys into a properly serialized (stringified) object. I imagine there's a missing step involving producing a new object or otherwise calling stringify in a special way.

Comment: What does "accessed behind-the-scenes" mean? The replacer function does not mutate the value. The return value of `JSON.stringify()` will exclude the keys. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#using_a_function_as_replacer. If you need the JS object from the JSON string, just do `JSON.parse(returnValue)`

Comment: If you could include a [mre], this might help

Comment: I believe removing the properties prior to serializing is the best way to go about this. One the object is parsed and properties reoved, you may serialize at will without worryingg about the warnings, etc.

Comment: @LinDu You would think that (I thought that) but it isn't so. `JSON.stringify()` appears to be reading all keys, even excluded ones (causing the warning), then excluding the key/value only in the final result. Check out the steps to reproduce I've included in the question.

Comment: @0stone0 done - see steps to reproduce in the question.

Comment: You can add a [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) function to your object to control how it's serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce()` on `Object.keys(obj)` to create a new object with only the properties you'd like. This way it won't trigger the getter.

Using spread syntax will trigger it, so that't not an option.

```js
const obj = {
  goodProperty: "Serialize Me",
  get badProperty() {
    console.log("Warning: Accessed deprecated property")
    return "deprecated";
  }
};

const excludeProperties = ["badProperty"];

const objWithoutBadProperties = Object.keys(obj).reduce((p, c) => {
    if (!excludeProperties.includes(c)) {
        p[c] = obj[c];
    }
    return p;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(objWithoutBadProperties));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is the solution I went with, as it doesn't require modifying the original Class or object.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) function to your object to get fine-grained control of your serialization:

```js
const obj = {
  goodProperty: "Serialize Me",
  get badProperty() {
    console.log("Warning: Accessed deprecated property")
    return "deprecated";
  },
};

obj.toJSON = function() {
    const exclude = [ "badProperty" ];
    const sanitizedObject = {};
    for (let prop in this) {
      if (!exclude.includes(prop)) sanitizedObject[prop] = this[prop];
    }
    return sanitizedObject;

    // Or, you can just return:
    // return { goodProperty: this.goodProperty };
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can now be certain that the bad properties will never be accessed when serializing the object, no matter when or where `stringify()` is called.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I don't own the Class, it comes from a 3rd party API, so my control lies only in what I do with it.

Comment: @Alain - Unless the prototype is sealed, you can add a function to it via assignment... or just directly to the object itself. I've updated the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it does seem valid in this format, although I ended up going with 0stone0's similar approach that simply builds and serializes sanitizedObject externally.

Answer (score 0):

FP style

```js
const obj = {
  goodProperty: "Serialize Me",
  get badProperty() {
    console.log("Warning: Accessed deprecated property")
    return "deprecated";
  },
  toJSON() {
    return Object.keys(this)
      .filter(k => !['badProperty'].includes(k))
      .reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur] = this[cur];
        return acc
      }, {})
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```